# Assembly version clashes in visual studio/team foundation server

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

We recently split our current work into two different VS solutions, one which contains mainly the front-end stuff (aspx files, user controls and the like) and the other which contained mainly business logic to compile into assemblies and reference in the first solution.

Since doing this we've been experiencing problems with versioning when building the business logic solution and trying to check the new dll's into the front-end solution. Most of the dll's (and pdb files) say that a newer version exists on the server.

I'm confused about this because when I went looking in the AssemblyInfo files of the projects in the Business Logic solution, they all had no version number set except the default of 1.0.0.0. Building the solution is currently generating files with version 2.2.1.3 and the server apparently has version 2.2.2.3 but nowehere can I see where these version numbers are being generated. Changing and rebuilding a project doesn't seem to change the version number unless I manually edit the version number in the AssemblyInfo of that project.

Can anyone suggest a way we can move forward on this, so that all the projects in the solution automatically update to the same version number when the solution is built, regardless of which developer is doing the build?

Cheers,
matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version number has nothing to do with the version number in the dll, but with the version of the file in source control.

You are trying to check in a file from which you don't have the latest yet. So undo your change, get the latest version of the files. Then check them out again and check them in.

Comment: Oddly, I had actually got the latest version before building and I was still getting this problem.

However, your answer pointed me in the right direction - I was indeed getting confused between version numbers and changeset numbers. So have a tick, thanks :)